# Scala performs multiple operations on the same object without repeating its name

Tags: scala

In kotlin, there is a `with` receiver function you can use to achieve following:

```
fun alphabet() = with(StringBuilder()) {
    for (letter in 'A'..'Z') {
        append(letter)
    }
    append("\nNow I know the alphabet!")
    toString() 
}
```

So you don't have to repeat the `StringBuilder` object. I am wondering what's the syntax of doing it in Scala?

Comment: The closest thing in Scala might be the `_` substitute for a passed-in parameter, but you can only reference the `_` once per parameter so it's not really the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more or less the same (as far as I can see from your example) as an import in Scala.

```
def alphabet = {
  val builder = new StringBuilder
  import builder._
  for(letter <- 'A' to 'Z') append(letter)
  append("\nNow I know the alphabet!")
  mkString // toString would be ambiguous unfortunately
}
```

Or you could go for a more functional looking approach with two extension methods. Let's call them `tap` and `pipe`.

```
implicit class TapExtensions[A](private val a: A) extends AnyVal {
  def tap[B](f: A => B): A = { f(a); a }
  def pipe[B](f: A => B): B = f(a)
}

def alphabet = 
  new StringBuilder()
    .tap( b => for(letter <- 'A' to 'Z') b.append(letter) )
    .tap( _.append("\nNow I know the alphabet!") )
    .pipe( _.toString )
```

Answer (score 1):

Typical functional [`.foldLeft`](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/collections.html#fold) is what you need in scala

```
('A' to 'Z')
    .foldLeft(new StringBuilder)((a, b) => a append b)
    .append("\nNow I know the alphabet!")
```

or `+` instead of `append`,

```
('A' to 'Z')
    .foldLeft(new StringBuilder)((a, b) => a + b)
    + "\nNow I know the alphabet!"
```

**output**

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Now I know the alphabet!
```

Comment: This isn't really the same thing (as you're repeating  `a`, the Stringbuilder)

Answer (score 0):

For the specific task you can also use the mkString function to get the result as you wanted 
This is what you could do

```
('A' to 'Z').mkString("") + 
"\nNow I know the alphabet!"
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Now I know the alphabet!
```

Hope this helps!